# C# not properly reading XMLNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I am trying to retrieve the "Name", "Value", and "Description" attributes from each node with a specific handler.

I'm specifically looking for every node named "VariantData" that has a type = "eContact". Then for each of those items I look at the child Row nodes and retrieve the Name, Value, and Description values of each.

The problem is that some of the items are retrieved, and others are not. Can someone help figure out why some of the items are not showing up? (see the result image at the end)

The full XML is located here:
[XML I'm Using](https://pastebin.com/SXYfJJ14)

Here's my C# Code  (I'm using Razor Syntax so ignore the HTML)

```
@using System.Xml;
@{
  string eContactName = "", eContactValue = "", eContactDescription = "";

  //Create The XML Document
  XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

  //Load the XML File
  xDoc.Load("D137506.xml");  //<!-- This is the exact same XML file in the link above (PasteBin)

  //Create a NodeList that gathers every "Row" from a "VariantData Type='eContact'" Node
  XmlNodeList xmlList = xDoc.SelectNodes("System/Components/Component/VariantData[@Type='eContact']/Row");

  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Value</th>
              <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

          @{
              foreach (XmlNode x in xmlList)
              {
                  eContactName = Convert.ToString(x.Attributes["Name"].Value);
                  eContactValue = Convert.ToString(x.Attributes["Value"].Value);
                  eContactDescription = Convert.ToString(x.Attributes["Description"].Value);

                  <tr>
                      <td>@eContactName</td>
                      <td>@eContactValue</td>
                      <td>@eContactDescription</td>
                  </tr>
              }
          }
      </tbody>
  </table>
}
```

[image]

Comment: How is the ordering done? I don't expect systemairflowdirection to be on top, given your XML. Are you also doing stuff client side? Could this be a styling glitch?

Comment: Make sure you are reading the supplied XML by changing one of the shown values, and seeing if it reflects on your page. It might still be you are confusing the XML file being read.

Comment: @nl-x I believe you are right. I just placed my XML file in the root directory of my solution explorer (D137506.xml). To test this, I renamed the file to D137506a.xml and I did the same in the code and now it can't find the file.  How am I supposed to reference the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a different file than you are thinking.

Use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` to check what the actual directory is, where your application is looking. And use `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory` or absolute or relative paths to specify where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the complete code. Maybe I missed something. I tried it out, and everything seemed to function properly. Have you stepped through it to determine any common denominators of the missing values for when you're running it?

below are my results:

[image]

Comment: Consider putting this like a comment with a link to pastebin. this is not an answer

Comment: It is still helpful. I find it weird how the order of items is also different. I've double-checked the XML and the code...I have no idea how yours can be so different from mine

Comment: Thanks @nl-x I will do that. :)